# How to "pretty print" a python pandas DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, format

I am new to pandas and still amazed by what it can do, although sometimes also by how things are done ;-)

I managed to write a little script which will report on the number of missing values encountered in a timeseries, either in each month or in each year of the series. Below is the code which uses some dummy data for demonstration.

If I print the returned result (`print cnty` or `print cntm`), everything looks fine, except that I would like to format the datetime value of the index according to the resolution of my data, i.e. I would wish to have `2000    1000  10  15` instead of `2000-12-31   1000  10   15` for the annual output and `2000-01   744   10    15` for the monthly output. Is there an easy way to do this in pandas or do I have to go through some loops and convert things into "plain" python before printing it. Note: I do not know in advance how many data columns I have, so anything with fixed format strings per row wouldn't work for me.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt


def make_data():
    """Make up some bogus data where we know the number of missing values"""
    time = np.array([dt.datetime(2000,1,1)+dt.timedelta(hours=i)
                     for i in range(1000)])
    wd = np.arange(0.,1000.,1.)
    ws = wd*0.2
    wd[[2,3,4,8,9,22,25,33,99,324]] = -99.9   # 10 missing values
    ws[[2,3,4,10,11,12,565,644,645,646,647,648,666,667,669]]  =-99.9 # 15 missing values
    data = np.array(zip(time,wd,ws), dtype=[('time', dt.datetime),
                                            ('wd', 'f4'), ('ws', 'f4')])
    return data


def count_miss(data):
    time = data['time']
    dff = pd.DataFrame(data, index=time)
    # two options for setting missing values:
    # 1) replace everything less or equal -99
    for c in dff.columns:
        ser = pd.Series(dff[c])
        ser[ser <= -99.] = np.nan
        dff[c] = ser
    # 2) alternative: if you know the exact value to be replaced
    # you can use the DataFrame replace method:
##    dff.replace(-99.9, np.nan, inplace=True)

    # add the time variable as data column
    dff['time'] = time
    # count missing values
    # the print expressions will print date labels and the total number of values
    # in the time column plus the number of missing values for all other columns
    # annually:
    cnty = dff.resample('A', how='count', closed='right', label='right')
    for c in cnty.columns:
        if c != 'time':
            cnty[c] = cnty['time']-cnty[c]
    # monthly:
    cntm = dff.resample('M', how='count', closed='right', label='right')
    for c in cntm.columns:
        if c != 'time':
            cntm[c] = cntm['time']-cntm[c]
    return cnty, cntm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = make_data()
    cnty, cntm = count_miss(data)
```

Final note: is a there is a format method to DatetimeIndex, but unfortunately no explanation on how to use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `format` method of `DatetimeIndex` performs similarly to the `strftime` of a `datetime.datetime` object.

What that means is that you can use the format strings found here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm

The trick is that you have to pass a function `formatter` kwarg of the the `format` method. That looks like this (just as an example somewhat unrelated to your code:

```
import pandas
dt = pandas.DatetimeIndex(periods=10, start='2014-02-01', freq='10T')
dt.format(formatter=lambda x: x.strftime('%Y    %m    %d  %H:%M.%S'))
```

Output:

```
['2014    02    01  00:00.00',
 '2014    02    01  00:10.00',
 '2014    02    01  00:20.00',
 '2014    02    01  00:30.00',
 '2014    02    01  00:40.00',
 '2014    02    01  00:50.00',
 '2014    02    01  01:00.00',
 '2014    02    01  01:10.00',
 '2014    02    01  01:20.00',
 '2014    02    01  01:30.00']
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends how pretty you want it, but for most use cases it is as simple as:

`print(date[0])` (Where `date` is your DatetimeIndex variable.)

You'll get an output like:

`2019-04-26 12:00:00`